# Remove space between the string in value prompt

Tags: javascript, trim, prompt, cognos

I want to trim space between the string from a list prompt.I want to pass the parameter without spaces between the string.I tried using trim() but unable to get the expected output.I tried using Java script.
Please Help!!!

Comment: Do you want to trim spaces from the beginning and end of a string or do you want to remove spaces inside the string?

Answer (score 1):

Do not trim in your prompt by JavaScript.
Trim in Query item that you use.
Find a query that provides values for you prompt and

```
    trim([You query item])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var param = $('element').val().replace(/\s/g, '');
```

you need get value of your element(inside of callback of event or something else)
and remove all spaces.

```
.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

trim() remove spaces or any charecter(as parameter) at the beginning and end of string

param is a variable with resulting string without spaces in it

Comment: The problem with that solution is getting a handle for the actual HTML control in Cognos is problematic. Cognos provides an interface in 10.2+ where you can manipulate prompts indirectly through abstracted JavaScript objects but it's often difficult and unsupported to directly manipulate the HTML controls and structures Cognos renders.